# Pygame AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python, pygame

[I cant understand what is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udMNb.png)

[image]

```py
while done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key== pygame.K_RIGHT:
                figure.moveRight(screen)
            elif event.key== pygame.K_LEFT:
                figure.moveLeft(screen)
            else:
                figure.moveDown(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. There is no problem with this code.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mre]!

Comment: Could you please post your complete code, using a paste service?

Comment: AFAIK there is no error in this code. The error comes from elsewhere: maybe you have a variable named `event`? Anyways you are not using the "standard" Python editor. I don't know anything about the one you're using, but maybe a part of the PyGame library is missing?

Answer (score 0):

i still dont know what in problem was but i replaced pygame.KEYDOWN to pygame.KEYUP and the program started working well

Comment: Maybe that's the solution.